# Cassandra multiple connections save, not working [Python]

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

I have 2 cassandra clusters, my simple script is trying to read from one and write to another. As per the documentation [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/connections.html), I have a `registered_connection` (named) to the 2nd cluster and a default connection to the 1st cluster. I am able to query the different clusters using:

```
item = MyModel.filter(u_id=u_id).using(keyspace=KEYSPACE,connection=connection).first()
```

However when I try to write/save the item to another cluster using:

```
item.using(connection=connection).save()
```

it throws no error but also does not write to the Cluster. I verified this by querying the sink cluster. Am I missing something obvious from the documentation ?

PS: In the first scenario its the `ModelQuerySet` object that applies custom connection and in the save scenario its the `Model` object.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who stumbles upon the same problem and needs a solution. 
Please keep in mind this is a workaround so if a proper solution pops up here please follow that.

This Solution is based on the **assumption**:

1. You are using cassandra-driver==3.11.0 or lower, where connection
   registry is supported (Take a look [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/connections.html))
2. You have 2 or more clusters to handle and you have registered all named connections though the above API ([register_connection](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/connections.html#register-a-new-connection)). Make one of the connections default connection.

A little **background** about your problem:

When you use a `ModelSetQuery` object with different connections, it exhibits expected behaviour. So if you have a query like:

```
MyModel.filter(u_id=u_id).first()
```

You could easily specify the `keyspace` and the `connection` for such a Query with the `using` method:

```
MyModel.filter(u_id=u_id).using(keyspace=KEYSPACE, connection=connection).first()
```

You will observe that however `MyModel.using(connection=connection).save()` does not work.

**For the critically minded**:

You will observe that underneath `_execute_statement` method in `cassandra.cqlengine.query` has the `connection` variable as `None` and even though you set with `Model.__connection__` the `model._get_connection()` does not grab your connection name string. Just a Hint to get you started to look at the actual problem.

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION:** group your operations on each cluster together and before each cluster operation switch default connection to the appropriate cluster with `connection.set_default_connection("cluster_connection_name")`

So basically:

```
connection.set_default_connection("cluster1")
# operations and queries on cluster 1
....
connection.set_default_connection("cluster2")
# operations and queries on cluster 2
....
```

Hope this helps!